# use clasp run with the default project of a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

According to https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md you have to create a GCP project to use `clasp run`.

Is it possible to use `clasp run` with the default project that gets created automatically for Google Apps Script projects?

Our company uses G-Suite but we do not have access to create GCP projects -- we do everything through the default ones created in GAS.

I'd like to be able to develop and run Google Apps Script code locally using `clasp run` but can't figure out how to get it to work with the default projects.

Comment: `Our company uses G-Suite but we do not have access to create GCP projects` Get access from admin?

Comment: You should take a look at [the codelab for clasp](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/clasp/#0) as well as [the documentation for it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp), they can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have read all of those and none of them get into how to use `clasp run` with the default Apps Script–managed Cloud Platform project.

Comment: @TheMaster Tried that but no dice. Are you saying there is no way to use `clasp` with the default GCP project?

Comment: I've never tried it before. You need at least need project id. If you can see it(Resources>Cloud platform-project) copy and paste it in clasp. Assuming you need no other authorizations, clasp run will work.

Comment: That doesn't give you a project ID. You can get a Project Key and Script ID from the project properties but I don't think those will work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use `clasp run` with the default project that gets created automatically for Google Apps Script projects?

I was wondering about this same question but found no definitive answer anywhere like you. So I decided to try by actually doing it.

TLDR; the answer is "Yes".

However in your case, you may have an issue getting the default `Project ID` and creating another OAuth credential if you do not have access to GCP. The default project is created under `Organisation > system-gsuite > apps-script`.

Here's what I did

1. Follow the [Setup Instructions](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md#setup-instructions).
2. Skip step 2 & 3 since we already have a default GCP project.
3. Get your default `Project ID` (something like sys-***********)
4. Run `clasp setting projectId sys-***********`
5. Follow step 4 to create a **new** OAuth 2.0 Client ID. There is a default client ID but there is no credential to download, so create a new one with the same step.
6. Follow step 5 to login
7. `clasp run`

Up to here I encountered an issue with `Could not read API credentials. Are you logged in globally?` which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103988/clasp-could-not-read-api-credentials-are-you-logged-in-globally) and this [github issue](https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/506) helps.
However I do not believe this issue is related.