# Clasp Could not read API credentials. Are you logged in globally?

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I'm logging in with `clasp login --creds <file>` which produces a local .clasprc.json file. 
It says that I am logged in, but when I run another command I get:

`Could not read API credentials. Are you logged in globally?`

Any thoughts on why its not looking at my local clasprc file first?

Currently using version clasp v. 2.2.0

Comment: Ran into the same issue, do you happen to have a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838607/clasp-local-login You can try this, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem on Windows 10 and found that you need to login both globally and locally to use `clasp run`. There should be a .clasprc.json file in both your project folder and user folder.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me.  In addition I had changed my nvm default version so the global login was no longer valid causing this error.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following command in the terminal/cmd to login globally

```
npx clasp login
```

Source: https://youtu.be/KxdCIbeO4Uk?t=230

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally found the solution for the same problem
Follow along with the comments from [this github issue](https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/506) 
Add the "oauthScopes" field to your local code and push it to your app
If you can't push, then copy-paste it to manifest file in the browser
Then you have to publish the app, and there were few things I've done, not sure which one helped. In the app in browser:

- add the app version in File->Manage Versions
- Publish -> Deploy as API executable
- try to login with clasp and creds.json file
- try to run something `clasp run testRun`

it may show the error that you're missing some oauth permissions, but it will list which ones, and you can add them

In my case, one weird thing that also helped was to enable some Google API
so in the app in browser: Resources -> Advanced Google Services -> enable some API
then try to do `clasp run`
if it works, you can disable the API that you have enabled previously.

Hope that helps

Comment: If you follow this github issue https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/506, do not `clasp logout` which is what caused the `Could not read API credentials. Are you logged in globally?` message. Answer from @utopion is correct.